# Any possible way to invert a function built from a sum of two?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

In searching for various choices for the interpolation of exponential-towers to fractional heights (aka tetration) I came to the following type of function:
$$ f_b(x) =\left[ \frac {t_0}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} v_k \cdot (x-t_0)^k \right] + \left[ \frac{t_1}{2} +  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} w_k \cdot (x-t_1)^k \right]$$
 which is an analytical formula for the doubly-infinite alternating series of the exponential-towers of consecutive heights (for $ ...+\log_b(\log_b(x))-\log_b(x) + x -b^x+b^{b^x}-...$ where $b$ is inside the range $]1 \ldots e^{\frac 1e}[$ and $t_0,t_1$ are the fixpoints, and the $x$ is in the range between the fixpoints - for what this information might be worth).

To find some smooth translation depending on another parameter I would like to have an inverse for that function, say I have some value for $f(x)$ and want to determine $x$; until now I apply Newton-iteration for this, but that is not much satisfying.

So perhaps there might be one clever idea how one could proceed to determine an inverse by some analytical formula.

[update]: After @Helge's comment I should perhaps add, that $f_b(x)$ seems to have no real fixpoint in the admissible range for $x$ and so the path, which is otherways the most straightforward one in more general problems, seems to be not viable here [/update]

Comment: Here's a general strategy. 1) Write as a power series around a single point $t$. 2) Invert this power series. There are "nice" expressions for 2). For 1) it depends on how you choose $t$.

Comment: @Helge: this seems to be impossible. To have a correct expression for the two-way-infinite series of iterated exponentials (towards the lower fixpoint $t_0$) and iterated logarithms (towards the upper fixpoint $t_1$) it was ***just essential*** to have the two power series developed around the respective fixpoint. Only then the power series can be made convergent (in case this is required by additional integer-iterations of $b^x$ resp. $\log_b(x)$ towards the resp. fixpoint) 